# How to create revision date php script?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have scrit which makes revision date from current date to 2 or x years later. What I need is to create script based on date which passed 2 days over. Let's say I need to make input record in mysql db for job that were done some days ago an put that date in table and calculate revision date from that date two or x years later. Does someone have an idea how to do that?

Part of my script:

```
$formDatum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formDatum']);

$date = new DateTime();

switch ($formUsluga) 
{
     case '1':
         $date -> modify("+2 year");
         $formRev=$date->format("Y-m-d H:i");
         break; 
     case '2': 
         date_add($date, new DateInterval("P2Y"));
         $formRev=$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
         break;
}
```

Comment: it's very difficult to understand what you want to achieve :/

Comment: @davogotland i need script not based on current date, but on date that i input in form which is some days earlier an calculate $formRev from that date for period 2 years later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to add 2 years to a date?

I believe you could do it like this:

```
$date = "2012-01-12";
$newdate = strtotime ( '+2 year' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );
```

EDIT:

Right... I didn't see that you had that part already. So you want to subtract the days that have past and then add the 2 years?

Comment: let' say that $date = "$_POST[formDatum]" (2012-01-08) and $newdate=strtotime('+2year',strtotime($date)); will be good case. Is it possible with this code?

Comment: @mdakic note that it's not '+2year', it's '+2 year'. with a space.

Comment: @davogotland that was tip mistake

Comment: Yes, i want to subtract the days that have past and then add the 2 years

Comment: But, what i want is not 2 year from now, i want to print 2 years from date that have past some days (2 or 7 or more)

Comment: Both my code and your code should work to do this. You can just take the date of the day you want to add 2 years to, for example... $date = new DateTime('2012-01-04');

Comment: @R34lthing thanks a lot for your last commnet that resolved the problem. $date = new DateTime($formDatum); in my case is good solution. Once again thanks a lot :-)